# ValueError: Number of informative, redundant and repeated features must sum to less than the number of total features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to generate a dataset for classification models using the code below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_features=2)

plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()
```

But this returns error:

> raise ValueError("Number of informative, redundant and repeated")
> ValueError: Number of informative, redundant and repeated features must sum to less than the number of total features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_features=2, n_informative=1, n_redundant=0, n_classes=1)
plt.plot(X,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]